# Label Control in Windows 8 App

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I am new to windows 8 app development and learning about app development in windows 8. 
I wanted to know whether there is any label like control available for windows 8 app development?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`TextBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.aspx) as a label like control.

Comment: Actually that link is for the TextBox. The correct link to the TextBlock documentation is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We have a UI Control that is called TextBlock  , its implementation is similar as that of label.
You can access its properties as
TextBox1.Text="your string";